# Except for me / except on me / except me

Tags: grammar

I was using panaroma to take a picture and it worked except my face was little distorted.

Is it grammatically correct to say

"Panaroma worked except for my face"

Or should it be

"Panaroma worked except on my face"

Or

"Panaroma worked except my face"

It'll be really helpful if you could explain to me why which one is right or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use [work](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work) in the sense **be effective or successful**,  is intransitive, so you need a preposition- in this case **for**- to provide additional information about what worked. There are two options:

> Panaroma worked except **for** my face
>
> Panaroma worked **for** everything except my face

The **on** option is not ok because that would be talking about the surface of something- you could use it, for example, for a medical cream:

> The cream worked except **on** my face

The third option is not OK because there is no preposition.

Answer (score 0):

1st and 2nd both sentences grammatically correct

But 1st one is more appropriate in this case ,You can use 2nd statement when you are talking about some thing which  you used physically.

For example you used any cream.it worked for your body but it don't give any result on your face then you can say "this cream worked except on my face".

3rd statement grammatically not correct as Conjunction is missing there.

Answer (score 0):

You need a preposition before "me". Otherwise "me" would be the direct object of "worked", but "worked" does not take a direct object when used with this sense.

A direct object is the thing that the verb acts on directly. Like, "I read the book." The book is the thing that I read. But in this case, "worked" means "operated successfully". There is no thing that is worked. Panorama didn't work your face -- I'm not sure what that would mean. If you said, "Panorama distorted my face" you wouldn't need a preposition, because your face is the thing that was distorted, the thing directly acted on.

As to which preposition ... both "for" and "on" work here. I have to disagree with other posters who say that "on" is doesn't work. We routinely say that something "worked on X but not on Y", meaning that it operated successfully in regards to X but not to Y. Which preposition to use in English is often tricky.

Comment: Since "my face" is the direct object of the sentence "panaroma distorted my face", is it grammatically correct to say "panaroma distorted except my face"? Or does it have to be "...except for my face"? @Jay

Comment: You have to list something that was affected before you use "except". You could say, "Panorama distorted everything except my face" or "Panorama distorted all the faces except mine".